# TypeScript define interface for "as X"

Tags: typescript, types, interface, typing

I have the following code:

```
const [surveyResponses, totalCount]: [SurveyResponse[], number] =
await this.someRepo.findByFilters(filter) as [SurveyResponse[], number];
```

Is it possible to give the `as [SurveyResponse[], number]` portion an interface? The `findByFilters` function returns either a paginated result or not, so I'd like to have an interface for each.

Comment: Note that you don't need both the `[SurveyResponse[], number]` annotations, only one or the other.

Comment: Nope, findByFilters returns either only an array of SurveyResponse or as in the question. tsc will throw an error if I don‘t defined it.

Comment: No, you don't need both. The `as` assertion is enough to define the type, or if it's assignable to the tuple type with annotation you don't need the assertion, but if not you certainly don't need *both*, just the assertion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an interface but a type alias, yes:

```
type X = [SurveyResponse[], number];

const [surveyResponses, totalCount]: X = ...
await this.someRepo.findByFilters(filter) as X;
```